# stop execution when you click "Run the current line or selection"

Tags: r, rstudio

In RStudio, is there a way to stop the execution of your script in case you execute a selection?

My problem is that most of "my users" love to select the whole script and click "Run the current line or selection (Ctrl+Enter)" instead of sourcing the script.

I have some `stop` commands inside my script, to stop execution and warn the user what is wrong. But selecting everything and running, the script will just continue. Is there a way around this, to force the ongoing execution to stop?

just a minimal example:

```
if(TRUE) stop('stop here')
print('continue')
```

I guess it is easier to explain people not to execute the selection but sourcing, but this anyhow often happens in my working group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `{}`for all project like :

```
{if(TRUE)  stop('stop here')
print('continue')
}
```

than Ctrl+A Ctrl+Enter

give you

```
> {if(TRUE) 
+   stop('stop here')
+ 
+ print('continue')
+ }
Error: stop here
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. Do you have a source or an explanation for this? It basically groups the code and gets executed as one? So in the End I could add these brackets at the beginning and end of the script and it should do the trick, correct.

Comment: I havent good explanation, but in my practice all what in `{}` executed as on section